# Can the word much be an antonym of a bit?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, antonyms

There is a question from a English text book:

Mr. X is a bit taller than Mr. Y. The antonym of the word **a bit** here means:

*1. a lot   2. much   3. adequate  4. a little*

The answer is given by the textbook is **a lot**

My question is why **much** can not be an answer.

Comment: **Much** certainly could be an answer. You can't always trust what text books say. The compiler might have thought that the phrases **a bit** and **a lot** looked good framed against each other. But as far as the meaning is concerned, **much** is just as valid

Comment: Both answers are equally correct in American formal and colloquial English. In fact, I'd much prefer "much" to "a lot" in formal language!